# Mark a Spring Boot bean as provided externally in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, annotations

I have written the following code **in a library**:

```
@Bean
public SomeObject bean(Argument argument) {
    return argument.createInstance();
}
```

The `Argument` object is provided by the **library caller**. This means the argument is not available for injection at compilation time, which makes IntelliJ complain with the following *warning* message:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'Argument' type found.

Adding the following annotation to the `Argument` object solves the problem:

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
```

However, this seems like a hacky way to circumvent the problem.

**Does Spring Boot have a mechanism or annotation for indicating that a bean is provided at runtime?**

Comment: Try adding spring.factories to the library resources/META-INF.  It tells the bean factory that library beans should be loaded.  IntelliJ will pick them up that way.

Comment: I have the configuration class that loads this bean listed in `spring.factories`. My problem is that the `Argument` object is provided by a different project entirely - which imports this library. :(

Comment: Argument.class has to appear in a spring.factories somewhere.